# Jersey. How to generate json and xml output depending on url param

Tags: java, xml, json, jaxb, jersey

Here is a `Jersey` service:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response service(@QueryParam("format") String format) {

  if (format.equals("json")) {...}

  return response;

}
```

I want to generate `XML` or `JSON` response back depending on **url param** "format".

My **response** instance is forming by `jaxb2`

I know I may get `xml` or `json` response back if on my Java client / functional test by using this code:

```
String content = service.path("").queryParam("myparam", "myvalue").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class);
```

or

```
String content = service.path("").queryParam("myparam", "myvalue").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

But I need to do it depending on url param.

Comment: If you could send a proper `ContentType` parameter, `application/json` instead of `json`, then you could use `MediaType.valueOf(format)` to get the `MediaType` instance and use it with the accept method.

Comment: Is your issue that you don't know how to set the response's content-type, or...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the media type of response entity directly via [Response#ok](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#ok%28java.lang.Object,%20javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29) (assuming you want to return `HTTP 200` status) method

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response service(@QueryParam("format") String format) {
    return Response
            // Set the status, entity and media type of the response.
            .ok(entity, "json".equals(format) ? MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON : MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .build();
}
```

or by using [Response.ResponseBuilder#header](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html#header%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response service(@QueryParam("format") String format) {
    return Response
            // Set the status and Put your entity here.
            .ok(entity)
            // Add the Content-Type header to tell Jersey which format it should marshall the entity into.
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "json".equals(format) ? MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON : MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is not the proper way to do what you want. You shouldn't be using a query parameter to determine output format. You have declared that your resource method produces both XML and JSON, the standard compliant way is to let the client send a proper HTTP "Accept" header which declares what media types they are able to consume. If they send in "Accept: application/json", your JAX-RS implementation should choose to format your method's response as JSON, if the client sends "Accept: application/xml", it should automatically format your response as XML. If the client indicates they can accept either, your JAX-RS implementation is free to choose either and you shouldn't care. If the client indicates they can't accept either, your JAX-RS should send back an appropriate HTTP error code indicating they don't have a way to send back a proper response.

Comment: I might miss smth/ but that "this is not the proper way" is not completely correct. What if he wants to create an OData Service for example? It's even within the standard that it must a query parameter $format for selecting the output format.

Comment: I didn't know anything about OData until I saw your response, have never used it. I based my answer on what I knew about REST principles at the time. I'll take your word that OData does this but still doesn't seem right as REST is supposed to be based on leveraging HTTP standards, and determining output format from a query parameter is not any kind of HTTP standard that I know of.

Comment: I agree that where possible, REST should always stick to the standards.  It is interesting that any service would require the data type as a query parameter -- it would seem the authors were not well versed on REST, or that it is not REST, just REST-like.

Answer (score 1):

Here the complete example, the above answer is right. I also use the above approach but facing problem while working with List. I set the entity like this:

```
public Response getCoursesJSONOrXML(@QueryParam("type") String type){
    //Here we get list
    List<Course> entity= courseService.getAllCourses();
    Response response = Response
            .ok(entity, "xml".equals(type) ? MediaType.APPLICATION_XML : MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
    return response;
}
```

After that I'm facing this exception:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

After reading jersey document, I found the solution that we need to use *GenericEntity* for our course list. Here the example

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getCoursesJSONOrXML(@QueryParam("type") String type){
    //Here we get list
    List<Course> list = courseService.getAllCourses();
    GenericEntity<List<Course>> entity = new GenericEntity<List<Course>>(list) {};
    Response response = Response
            .ok(entity, "xml".equals(type) ? MediaType.APPLICATION_XML : MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Since we are talking about things outside the pattern here let me try something:

How about you use a filter (look for com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilterFactory) on your service and change (or add or overwrite) the accept header based on your query param?

Not the most honest approach, I admit it, but i think you should give it a try